# Collectd - сборщик статистики для linux

Tags: linux

Доброго времени суток, камрады.

Решил поиграться с этим демоном. Документация конечно не блещет информативностью. Ghj нотификации и thresholds вообще ничего не нашел в ней. :(

Самое важное для меня это разобраться с настройкой нотификаций. Не могу доконца понять как настраивать нотификации, например, по доступности хоста. Может кто пример приведет? Попробовал вот так, но не работает:

```
<Plugin ping>    <Type "droprate">        Instance "192.168.56.110"        FailureMax 1    </Type></Plugin>
```

хост 100% в дауне, какие нюансы?
Версия collectd - 5.1

В идеале если кто может рабочий конфиг дать посмотреть -- буду безмерно признателен!
Так же буду очень признателен за какиелибо более развернутые примеры либо описания и решения задач.

pps; метки не могу создавать, поэтому пометить как collectd не могу(

Comment: [Тут смотрели?][1]пишут что liboping еще нуна  [1]: https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Ping#Synopsis

Comment: спасибо за ссылку на этот же вопрос)Графики рисуются, соответственно liboping есть, ну и по факту он есть) меня волнует вопрос с оповещениями и threshold'ами :) я их не могу настроить, все остальное работает без проблем.

Comment: Кому интересно, написал [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/162087/) на хабре

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена. Нотификации побеждены, действительно, в версии 5.х поменялась труктура графиков, следовательно поменялось и обращение к ним для создания нотификаций. к примеру для реакции на отсутсвие пинга на любой настроенный хост в плагине ping необходимо написать в threshold'e следующее:

```
<Plugin "ping">    <Type "ping_droprate">        FailureMax 0.9    </Type></Plugin>
```

для плагина df для нотификации на достижение определенного занятого места нужно написать следующее:

```
<Plugin "df">    Instance "root"    <Type "df_complex-used">            WarningMax 4025360000            FailureMax 6025360000            Percentage false    </Type></Plugin>
```